# Putting 2 maps together under condition in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm new in GEE.

I've made 2 maps: dNBR and NBRpost

and I just want to make 1 resulting risk map that put both together under the condition:

dNBR below threshould1 Not burned
NBRpost below threshould2 Moderate

NBRpost above threshould2 Extreme

I started to make filters like:

```js
var filt1=(ee.Filter.lt(dNBR, -2));
var filt2=(ee.Filter.lt(NBRpost, -233));
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do [per-pixel 'band math' on a set of images](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_math), which doesn't involve using filters.

Here is a snipped of example code, using your variables:

```js
var burned = dNBR.gte(threshold1);
var not_burned = dNBR.not();
var moderate_burn = burned.and(NBRpost.lte(threshold2));
var extreme_burn = burned.and(NBRpost.gt(threshold2));
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I combine those 4 variables into 1 single map?